# setFlashMode causes crash for Apple reviewer

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I have received a crash log from App Review, where the line in my camera view that sets the flash mode to "Off" is causing a crash. Here is the code snippet:

```
let cameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: self.backCameraDevice)
            do {
                try cameraInput.device.lockForConfiguration()

                if cameraInput.device.isExposureModeSupported(AVCaptureExposureMode.ContinuousAutoExposure) {
                    cameraInput.device.exposureMode = AVCaptureExposureMode.ContinuousAutoExposure
                }

                if cameraInput.device.isFocusModeSupported(AVCaptureFocusMode.ContinuousAutoFocus) {
                    cameraInput.device.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusMode.ContinuousAutoFocus
                }


                // CRASH HERE
                self.backCameraDevice.flashMode = .Off


                cameraInput.device.unlockForConfiguration()
            } catch {
            }
```

What is the proper way to set the flash mode while loading the camera view?

Comment: What do you do in the `catch` for that `try`?  Have you tested your app on an iPad (i.e. a device that doesn't have a flash)?

Comment: Oh you raise a good point. Perhaps I should add a check in there like I did for the other settings. updated my question with an example.

Comment: It sounds like  a good first step; you should check `isFlashModeSupported` and/or `hasFlash`

Answer (score 0):

you can use 2 way

1 )

```
 let avDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

    // check if the device has torch
    if avDevice.hasTorch {
        // lock your device for configuration
        do {
            let abv = try avDevice.lockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            print("aaaa")
        }

        // check if your torchMode is on or off. If on turns it off otherwise turns it on
        if avDevice.torchActive {
            avDevice.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.Off
        } else {
            // sets the torch intensity to 100%
            do {
                let abv = try avDevice.setTorchModeOnWithLevel(1.0)
            } catch {
                print("bbb")
            }
        //    avDevice.setTorchModeOnWithLevel(1.0, error: nil)
        }
        // unlock your device
        avDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
    }
```

2 )

```
let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    if (device.hasTorch) {
        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()
            if (device.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchMode.On) {
                device.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.Off
            } else {
                try device.setTorchModeOnWithLevel(1.0)
            }
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You lock/unlock cameraInput.device but you set the flash on backCameraDevice.
You should do:

```
cameraInput.device.flashMode = .Off
```

Answer (score 0):

We have to set one of the supported flash modes only.
If a device does not support the flash feature, app crashes when the flash mode is changed programmatically.

So first of all, we have to check supported flash modes.

Here is a code snippet when you're going to use AVCapturePhotoSettings.

```
let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
if let flashModes = self.photoOutput?.supportedFlashModes {
    if flashModes.contains(self.flashMode) {
        settings.flashMode = self.flashMode
    }
}
```